# Pandas dataframe plot bar drops values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

While doing data analysis I uses the df.plot.bar method of pandas Dataframe to plot my results:

```
df.plot.bar(figsize=(15, 5), legend=None)
```

While doing some more research I noticed, that the plots look different in some cases. The reason for this is, that the plot.bar method starts to ignore information, when the figsize is too low.

My example had 31 bars per event and at `figsize=(10, 5)` less bars where plotted than at `figsize(15, 5)`.
Is this known and desired behaviour? Because without a warning the plot misses (important) information.

Dataframe:

```
                 Day(X-Axis in plot)
+------------+-----------------------+
| Id    +  Day1  |   Day2  |   Day3  ...
+------------+-----------------------+
| 0     + 0      |   20    |    0
| 1     | 300    |   10    |    400
| 3     + 20     |   0     |    400
| 4     | 60     |   0     |    800
...
+------------+-----------------------+
```

The values are the population of the specific id at a specific day.

Every id gets its own bar for every day. The dataframe is transposed with T in order to make plot.bar plot the days on the X axis.

`figsize=(10, 5)`

[image: figsize(10, 5)]

`figsize(15, 5)`

[image: figsize(15, 5)]

Comment: Can you add data and code to this question?

Comment: The scales in both plots are the same (7-22 days), but the plotted data differ. for example, for the 18-days bin, there is no data point/bar in the top plot. Adding a sample of your data may help.

Comment: Sample and description added. Both plots are made with exactly the same data, but different figsizes.

Comment: As an estimate: You have 31 rows and x columns. Bars take 80% of the space of a unit. The bar should at least be two pixels wide to be seen on screen. A usual figure has 10% margins on both side of the axes and has 100 dpi. Then you need a figure width of 2*x*31/0.8**2/100 ~= x inch. In other words, if you you have more than 15 columns, some bars might not be visible on a 15 inch wide figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest oh you mean it is there, but invisible on my screen? Makes sense.

Comment: Are the bars visible if you change the scale on the x-axis? I imagine the resolution just isn't great enough to see that many bars when the figure is smaller.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest But why can I see the other bars then? Shouldn't they all be scaled to the same size and therefore be "invisible"? Or is it only possible to see them, because they are really close together?

Comment: Yes, Matplotlib wouldn't eat data, but it might not plot things that are less than a pixel wide. Simplified, this means that if the left coordinate of a rectangle falls into the same pixel as the right coordinate of that rectangle no bar is drawn at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an estimate: You have 12 rows and 31 columns. Bars take 80% of the space of a unit. The bar should at least be two pixels wide to be seen on screen. A usual figure has 10% margins on both side of the axes and has 100 dpi. Then you need a figure width of 2*12*31/0.8**2/100 ~= 12 inch. In other words, if you you have more than 31 columns, some bars might not be visible on a 12 inch wide figure.

To make this reproducible, let's consider the following case where we have `N=20` rows and columns.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N=20
df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(np.ones(N)))

ax = df.plot.bar(legend=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here some bars are not visible. We can calculate that for 20 rows and 20 columns the figure would need to be `2*N**2/0.8**2/100. == 12.5` inch in width.

```
N=20
df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(np.ones(N)))

w = 2*N**2/0.8**2/100.
plt.rcParams.update({"figure.figsize" : (w, 4.8), "figure.dpi" : 100})
ax = df.plot.bar(legend=False)
```

Now it indeed shows all bars.

[image]

Of course a figure cannot be made arbitrarily large, so one might instead make sure the bars have an edgeline, which would be drawn independent of the extent of the rectangle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N=20
df = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(np.ones(N)))

ax = df.plot.bar(legend=False)
for bar in ax.patches:
    bar.set_linewidth(0.72)
    bar.set_edgecolor(bar.get_facecolor())
plt.show()
```

[image]